# Hostname won't resolve after setting up new server

Tags: networking, centos, dhcp, hostname

I just completed a fresh install of Centos 7 on a PC. It is connected to the campus network, so I am not in control of the DNS server. I gave it a hostname by setting the HOSTNAME value in /etc/sysconfig/network. I also set the DHCP_HOSTNAME value in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 and rebooted the system.

The problem is I cannot ping this machine from another arbitrary computer. I keep getting messages saying that the host doesn't exist.

What are some typical ways that a machine on DHCP gets its hostname tied to its ip address so that it will resolve? Is there a way to send the DHCP server my hostname?

Comment: the hostname and the DNS name does not have to be a match. Is there a DNS server setup in the campus? If yes, ask the admin to add your host to it. In a Windows Active Directory environment the registration of a Windows Client Domain Integrated System is done by the client as part of the domain. Non domain computers are not allowed to register themselves. This has to be done by the DNS admin. If you get your IP by DHCP you will be able to access it by IP (which probably will not change as long you don't have the computer powered off longer then the DHCP lease time)